# Add remove CSS class to nth parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add and remove css class with a link button on my web page to nth(ProdBox) parent:
Code below

```
<div class="prod-box shadow">
    <div class="prod-details">                    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="prod-compare">
    <div class="compare">
        <a href="javascript:void();" class="add-to-compare" data-id="123">Add to Compare</a>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

I want to replace the top parent class "prod-box shadow" with "prod-box shadow-blue".
I tried below jquery 1.9.1 code, but not working:

```
$(this).parent('div .prod-box').removeClass('shadow');
$(this).parent('div .prod-box').addClass('shadow-blue');
```

Answer (score 1):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is what you are looking for

```
$(this).closest('.prod-box').removeClass('shadow').addClass('shadow-blue');
```

use [toggleClasss()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to switch between the classes

```
$(this).closest('.prod-box').toggleClass('shadow shadow-blue');
```

The .parent() method only search for the direct parent element and the applies the given selector to that parent element

Comment: Thanks Arun, Little more favour required from you. Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DBfKz/17/ here parent.remove not wokring in jquery 1.9.1 while working in 1.4.2. You can try to add product and click on x button to remove them.

Comment: @user1610100 [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is removed in jQuery 1.9, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead like `$(document).on("click", ".box a", function () {` see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mSF67/1/